# Does python have a limitation on the amount of code in a module?

Tags: python, module, compilation

I have written a Python module designed to solve the Tetris cube tiling puzzle, and it contains a lot of code, but it doesn't want to run, when I press f5 to run the program, the shell restarts, but then stops working, even when I enable debugging nothing happens still. I put a print statement at the very start of the program, yet it is not executed, and I cannot terminate the program using ctrl-c. I was able to fix this problem by putting some of the functions I had defined into a separate module, and now it works fine, but if I create a new function, and add enough print statements, the problem reappears, but can be fixed by just removing one statement.
The version of Python I am using is Python 2.7.8

Comment: How big is the code? Can you upload it somewhere (a github gist or something) so we can attempt to reproduce? I am *very* skeptical that the amount of code is the issue, there is no reason for this to be a problem at all, or if it was, for it to *hang* instead of giving an error message. I suspect you inadvertently introduced an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Like @delnan said, I highly doubt your code is that long for Tetris. Try to pinpoint the error as much as possible then post the code. I'm sure you can get it to a "post-able" amount.

Comment: Here is the git: https://gist.github.com/micsthepick/6029583690c5297df215. When I execute the module, even the print statement at the start does not execute, So I do not believe it is a problem with my code

Comment: The program is a solver for a tiling puzzle, which just happened to be named the Tetris cube. I was able to get the code to work by splitting it into two seperate modules, and if I delete a function and replace it with just enough print statements, in a new function, it doesn't run, but I can get it to start working by deleting just one statement.

Comment: Also the problem does not occur when the module is run from an import statement, just when running from the idle interpreter.

Comment: If someone could try running it on their own computer, I believe it is only a bug with my version of python on my computer. If it works on other computers, then I will see if I can update python, otherwise, hopefully you will see that it isn't my fault. There are no infinite loops in my code, it just wont run unless I split the code between modules or run it a different way, such as an import statement. @JGerulkis

Comment: Running any module which is long enough straight from idle by pressing f5 seems to freeze the interpreter, but importing works fine, can anyone else run large enough (300 + lines) .py files with the same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been an issue with the version of python I had installed. A new installation is able to run long modules fine, without any noticeable delay even from pressing f5 to first print statement.